# Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I'd like a regexp or other string which can replace everything except alphanumeric chars (`a-z` and `0-9`) from a string. All things such as `,@#$(@*810` should be stripped. Any ideas?

Edit: I now need this to strip everything but allow dots, so everything but `a-z, 1-9, .`. Ideas?

Comment: When you say "strip everything", you don't want to map Unicode to nearest ASCII ("ASCII hammer")? So you're ok with *Münchener Straße* -> *Mnchener Strae* and not *Muenchener Strasse*?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9.]+/i", "", $string);
```

Matches one or more characters not a-z 0-9 [case-insensitive], or "." and replaces with ""

Comment: How can i change that to allow only dots (i.e .)?

Comment: You don’t need to escape the dot inside the character set.

Comment: Do you really need the `+` sign? Someone posted below without the `+` sign.

Comment: @kuchi: very old question but i just came across it: it does NOT make a difference if you replace with an empty string. it DOES make a difference if you replace with something else, say a dash (`"-"`). With the `+` it will change `"test$!§test"` to `"test-test"`. Without the `"+"` it gets changed to `"test---test"`

Answer (score 21):

I like using [^[:alnum:]] for this, less room for error.

```
preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', '', "(ABC)-[123]"); // returns 'ABC123'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/[^a-z0-9.]/
```

should do the trick

Comment: How can i change that to allow only dots (i.e .)?

Comment: Full reg exp please? I don't know the syntax

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$string = preg_replace ('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $string);
```

/i stands for case insensitivity (if you need it, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This also works to replace anything not a digit, a word character, or a period with an underscore.  Useful for filenames.

```
$clean = preg_replace('/[^\d\w.]+/', '_', $string);
```