# Remove characters not in a set in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I'm trying to remove all characters that are not alphanumeric nor in this set

```
'''!$%*()_-=+\/.,><:;'"?|'''.
```

I know this removes all non alphanumeric characters but how can I do better?

```
re.sub(r'\W+','',line)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Python 2.x non-regex solution:

```py
punctuation = '''!$%*()_-=+\/.,><:;'"?|'''
allowed = string.digits + string.letters + punctuation
filter(allowed.__contains__, s)
```

The string to filter is `s`.  (This probably isn't the fastest solution for long strings.)

Comment: "how can I do better?" How is this better?

Comment: @JBernardo: It actually does what the OP wants, in contrast to the given regex-based solution, which also strips out the punctuation.

Comment: It seems OP doesn't want punctuation... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JBernardo: The OP wants to remove "characters that are not alphanumeric nor in this set", i.e. the punctuation in the given set should *not* be removed.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I'll have to see now how efficient it is as I have about 10GB of text to go through.

Comment: It's fast enough actually. It takes about 1 hour to go over 10GB of text on my laptop.

Answer (score 4):

With credit to this thread: [Remove specific characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

First, there's no need to retype all the punctuation manually. The string module defines string.punctuation as a property for your convenience. (Use `help(string)` to see other similar definitions available)

```
>>> import string
>>>string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

The exact application of the solution will take some fiddling to define undesired characters; a big downside is that in this form, it only removes the characters you tell it to remove. If you're sure your file is 100% ASCII characters, then you could define:

```
>>> delchars = ''.join(c for c in map(chr, range(256)) if c not in (string.punctuation + string.digits + string.letters) )
```

You can filter characters by throwing them out:

```
>>> text.translate(None, delchars)
```

EDIT: Here's some interesting timing information for the various methods:
[Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: While `str.translate()` can be used for this purpose (and is probably faster than the solution I gave), the exact given code *removes* punctuation, while the OP wants to *retain* the punctuation in the given set.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I've adjusted my solution accordingly. You might also be interested in the link to performance tests done in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, you can use the `translate` method on string to remove characters you do not want:

```
>>> def remove(string, characters):
        return string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', characters))

>>> import string
>>> remove(string.printable, string.ascii_letters + string.digits + \
                             '''!$%*()_-=+\/.,><:;'"?|''')
'#&@[]^`{}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```