# Replace all non-alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: python

I have a string with which i want to replace any character that isn't a standard character or number such as (a-z or 0-9) with an asterisk. For example, "h^&ell`.,|o w]{+orld" is replaced with "h*ell*o*w*orld". Note that multiple characters such as "^&" get replaced with one asterisk. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Short example `re.sub(r'\W+', '_', 'bla: bla**(bla)')` replaces one or more consecutive non-alphanumeric characters by an underscore.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Regex to the rescue!

```
import re

s = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '*', s)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '*', 'h^&ell`.,|o w]{+orld')
'h*ell*o*w*orld'
```

Comment: If you handle unicode a lot, you may also need to keep all non-ASCII unicode symbols: `re.sub("[\x00-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7F]+", " ", ":%# unicode ΣΘΙП@./\n")`

Comment: If you want to keep spaces in your string, just add a space within the brackets: s = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+', '*', s)

Comment: If doing more than one replace, this will perform slightly quicker if you pre-compile the regex, e.g., `import re; regex = re.compile('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+'); regex.sub('*', 'h^&ell.,|o w]{+orld')`

Comment: Also note `\W` is for non-word characters, it's almost the same but allows the underscore as a word character (don't know why): https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#index-32

Comment: You don't need the '+' in the regex

Comment: @Serg: The OP wanted to replace multiple consecutive characters with a single `*` - hence, the `+` in the regex.

Answer (score 62):

The pythonic way.

```
print "".join([ c if c.isalnum() else "*" for c in s ])
```

This doesn't deal with grouping multiple consecutive non-matching characters though, i.e.

`"h^&i => "h**i` not `"h*i"` as in the regex solutions.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
s = filter(str.isalnum, s)
```

in Python3:

```
s = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, s))
```

Edit:
realized that the OP wants to replace non-chars with '*'. My answer does not fit

Answer (score 16):

Use `\W` which is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Check the documentation, https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
import re
s =  'h^&ell`.,|o w]{+orld'
replaced_string = re.sub(r'\W+', '*', s)
output: 'h*ell*o*w*orld'
```

update: This solution will exclude underscore as well. If you want only alphabets and numbers to be excluded, then solution by nneonneo is more appropriate.

Comment: Note that *`\W` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`* only in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, `\W+` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` only if `re.ASCII` / `re.A` flag is used.

Comment: Updated [link to the documentation of re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), search for `\W` in the page "Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched."