# Replace all non-alphabet in a string

Tags: python, string

That is to replace all digits, special characters, non-printing characters. I can't use the `re` library.

```
line = line.rstrip() # this get rids of the white spaces
if character in string.digits or character in string.punctuation:
    line = line.replace(character, "")
```

However, this does not get rid of `\`; how can I check for this and replace it with nothing? `character in "\"` does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all non-alphanumeric characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985456/replace-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Why can't you use the re library? It's a standard library. Is this homework?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash (as it is usually used to escape other characters): `'\\'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over the string and keep any alphabetic characters. You can do this with a list comprehension and a join.

```
import string
line = ''.join(c for c in line if c in string.ascii_letters)
```

Although you can better handle unicode strings with `isalpha()`:

```
>>> line = u'ABcdef124__++--()zyxôôô999٤end'
>>> print(''.join(c for c in line if c.isalpha()))
ABcdefzyxôôôend
```

so `ô` (LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX) is retained, but `٤` (ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FOUR) is not, which seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should protect "\". Use "\\"

Comment: Also, I don't think that it is good idea to delete "\" because it can protect some special symbols

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `str.isalpha()` to check whether a charcter is alphabetic or not:

```
>>> st='hsfjebhjbe283628362et#@%\\\\\\\\\\\\\\!!@$*)(|<>~\%^%@%^///;...][]=--]9988bjwqgvs'
>>> ''.join(i for i in st if i.isalpha())
'hsfjebhjbeetbjwqgvs'
```

For alphanumeric use `str.isalnum()`:

```
>>> ''.join(i for i in st if i.isalnum())
'hsfjebhjbe283628362et9988bjwqgvs'
```