# create a directory name from a string in python

Tags: python, filesystems

What's the most idiomatic, clean way to convert a descriptive string to a portable directory name?

Something like `description.replace(" ", "_")` but that also removes / replaces punctuations and other whitespaces, and maybe other edge cases I haven't thought about.

The mapping can be lossy (you don't need to be able to reproduce the original string), it just needs to be a reasonable approximation to the given description, and of course - if there's a standard implementation somewhere that's a big bonus

Thanks!

Example:
`"I'm thinking Avocado toast" -> "im_thinking_avocado_toast"`

Comment: Unless the input is always in English, the first step should be IMO this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/517923/5378816 . Then continue with replacing remaining non-ascii-alphanums as suggested.

Comment: Your use of str.replace() will **not** replace anything apart from space

Comment: @Codist that's right, this was just meant to illustrate the type of modification needed, hence the "but that also removes / replaces punctuations and other whitespaces..."

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985459/9398584) explains how to replace all non-alphanumeric characters by a character, I guess that's good enough:

`re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '_', description).lower()`

```
In [6]: re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '_', "I'm thinking Avocado toast").lower()
Out[6]: 'i_m_thinking_avocado_toast'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all changes step by step. I recommend to use [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for such cases.

```
import re

description = "I'm thinking Avocado toast!"
cleaned_description = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', description)
cleaned_description = re.sub(r'\s+', '_', cleaned_description).lower()
print(cleaned_description)
```

Answer (score 0):

For maximum flexibility you may build a translation table with `str.maketrans` and use it with `str.translate`. Suppose you want to convert some characters to underscores, some to hyphens, and simply ignore some other. That's as simple as in this (admittedly rather silly) example

```
trans = str.maketrans(" .()", "__--", "'/*")
"I'm thinking (Avocado) toast".translate(trans)

'Im_thinking_-Avocado-_toast'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can see for this, using only vanilla python would be this:

```
str = "I am thinking about Avocado Toast"
str_list = str.lower().split()
new_str = ""
for index, item in enumerate(str_list):
    new_str += item
    if index != len(str_list) - 1:
        new_str += "_"
```

What this does is just simply splitting the string on the white spaces, placing the parts of it in a list, and then constructing a new string from its parts. The `if statement` in the loop is to check whether the end has been reached, in which case, no under line whole be added.