# Remove \n from triple quoted string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, strip

I have the following string:

```
string = """
Hello World
123
HelloWorld
"""
```

I want to clear all the line-breaks from the string in python.

I tried

```
string.strip()
```

But it's not working as desired.

What I should do?

I'm using python 3.3

Thanks.

Comment: `string.replace('\n', '')` not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes whitespace from the start and the end of the string.

```
>>> string
'\nHello World\n123\nHelloWorld\n'
>>> string.strip()
'Hello World\n123\nHelloWorld'
```

If you want to remove the new line characters *inside* of the string, you can replace them by something else using [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> string.replace('\n', ' ')
' Hello World 123 HelloWorld '
```

Answer (score 22):

I would like to point out that, depending on how that triple-quoted string is being used, you could avoid the issue entirely.

In Python triple-quoted strings, you can put a backslash ("`\`") at the end of a line to ignore the line break. In other words, you can use it to put a line break at that spot in your code without making a line break in your string.

For example:

```
"""line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3"""
```

will actually become

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

if printed or written to some file or other output.

Using it this way can eliminate any need for a function to replace the line breaks, making your code clearer and cleaner.

EDIT:

If you're using backslash line continuations like this, you can also use simple single-quoted strings the same way;

```
"line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3"
```

is also equivalent to

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

Comment: Why would one need triple quotes AND backslash? Why not just backslash?

Comment: @AllDaniSpringer You could also do a single quoted string and it would work the same way; I just kept the triple quotes because that's what the question was asking about. I'll make an edit to mention that, though.

Answer (score 5):

Use `translate` instead of `replace` for this kind of operation.

```
>> string.translate(None, "\n")
Hello World123HelloWorld
```

You will realize how [fast translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python) is when you work with big files.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `str.replace`:

```
string.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The main question is already answered, but I would like to add that if you plan on **using** the individual lines you might be better off doing this -

```
string = """
Hello World
123
HelloWorld
"""
for line in string.strip().split('\n'):
    print(line)
    # do something with the line
```

**Output** from above code -

```
Hello World
123
HelloWorld
```

Comment: That’s no different to `print(string.strip())`.

Comment: But what if he wants to **use** individual lines?

Comment: That would be a different problem and nothing in the question suggests OP wants to do that.

Comment: I just wanted to show another way of doing it while describing it's specific use. Partial answer.