# Python Checking Characters

Tags: python, parsing, character

I am trying to parse text and determine if it contains only letters and numbers, not special keyboard symbols like ! and #. I tried using .isalpha, but it says ! and # are valid. Is there away I can have something return false if it encounters one of these symbols?

Comment: also dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: `>>> '!'.isalpha()
False` Lying when asking a question isn't the best way to obtain an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use regex matching:

```
import re

print re.match(r'^\w+$',your_string).group(0)
```

This matches the whole string only if it is alphanumeric

```
>>> print re.match(r'^\w+$', '1kjh2431k2j43').group(0)
'1kjh2431k2j43'

>>> print re.match(r'^\w+$', 'hjs7*Y@#kha9Y*@#').group(0)
NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

can check if the ordinals of the characters are in the ranges of characters, think the ranges are like 65-90ish and then 95-122ish, and then just check .isdigit() to see if the number was a digit beforehand

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your answer.  Since this question is marked as a duplicate, you should take a look at the referenced question and see if you can improve the answers there.    This helps to avoid repetition and guide people to the best available answers.