# How to remove special characers from a column of dataframe using module re?

Tags: python, string, pandas

Hey I have seen that link but nowhere there they have used `re` module that's why I have posted here. Hope you understand and remove the duplicate.

Here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python). I want to use `re` module.

Table:

```
A    B    C    D
1    Q!   W@   2
2    1$   E%   3
3    S2#  D!   4
```

here I want to remove the special characters from `column` `B` and `C`. I have used `.transform()` but I want to do it using `re` if possible but I am getting errors.

Output:

```
A    B    C    D   E   F
1    Q!   W@   2   Q   W
2    1$   E%   3   1   E
3    S2#  D!   4   S2  D
```

My Code:

```
df['E'] = df['B'].str.translate(None, ",!.; -@!%^&*)(")
```

It's working only if I know what are the special characters.

But I want to use `re` which would be the best way.

```
import re
#re.sub(r'\W+', '', your_string)
df['E'] = re.sub(r'\W+', '', df['B'].str)
```

Here I am getting error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

So how should I pass the value to get the correct output.

Comment: The answers for that dupe question aren't all that suitable here: use `str.replace('\W+', '')`. This uses `re.sub` under the hood.

Comment: You can use whatever `lambda` expression you like, such as `lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x)`.

Comment: Rahul, if that duplicate's answers just aren't enough to solve your issue, ping me (include "@TigerhawkT3" in a comment here) and I'll reopen this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was trying to use `re` and I don't know lamda usage here. That's why I posted it. In your given link they were removing only known characters. But your comment `str.replace('\W+', '')` what I wanted. If you post that as answer or lamda function how should I use. It would be grateful.

Comment: Sure, I'll reopen it and let @ajcr post with his `str.replace` solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column) shows, you can use `map()` with a `lambda` function that will assemble and return any expression you like:

```
df['E'] = df['B'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))
```

`lambda` simply defines anonymous functions. You can leave them anonymous, or assign them to a reference like any other object. `my_function = lambda x: x.my_method(3)` is equivalent to `def my_function(x): return x.my_method(3)`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try lamda in future for my queries.

Answer (score 41):

A one liner without `map` is:

```
df['E'] = df['B'].str.replace('\W', '')
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for OP's problem, but be aware that it also removes white spaces. If you want to keep spaces use:

`df['B'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')`