# How to delete data from a table with a particular column value?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, data-science

[image]

I want to drop the rows with Borough = '[Not assigned\n]' values. But the drop function is not working. Also, I want to remove brackets from start and end of each column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! I think your question may have been asked before-

To remove records based on a condition, answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13851535/9003184) question might help -

To remove special characters - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33257344/9003184) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50444346/9003184)