# How to remove all special char in string by python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all special char such as '|', '.' or '$' in the string.

Here is my code:

```
string= '#$#&^&#$@||||123515'
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', string)
print(string)
```

the output:

```
#$#&^&#$@||||123515
```

I know this regex means removing everything but number, a-z and A-Z.

But it fails to remove all special char.

Can somebody tell me why? Thank you! :)

Comment: [Assign the new value to `string`](https://ideone.com/RH1LrL)

Comment: I suggest removing the post.

Comment: I can't remove it since it has been answered... Deeply sorry about this!

Comment: If others agree with me, the question will get removed some time later.

Comment: Okay! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help:

```
>>> import re
>>> string= '#$#&^&#$@||||123515'
>>> string = re.sub('[\W\_]','',string)
>>> string
'123515'
```

Comment: `[^\w]` will not remove `_`, so this regex is not identical to OP regex.

Comment: @Mars Lee, please use the updated answer.

Comment: It is the same regex anyway. The only problem was assigning the value to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue with your code**: You have to store the response of `re` in `string` variable like `string = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', string)`. Then do `print(string)`.

**Alternative solution**: Your can also achieve this even without using regex:

```
>>> string = '#$#&^&#$@||||123515'
>>> ''.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum())
123515
```

Comment: This is [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python).