# Counting arguments in lists and printing lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, raw-input, phrase

I want users to enter random words/numbers/phrases. If they have entered more then 5 then they get an error message and if the enter 5 or less then I print out the list vertically. I don't know what code to use so that it does not count the white spaces. As well, I want to count the number of words/numbers, NOT the amount of characters. If you could just take a look at my code and give some help, that would be great!

```
myList = [] 

myList = raw_input("Enter words,numbers or a phrase (a phrase should be entered between two quotations)...")

if len(myList) > 5:
print('Error')

else:
#print output
for variable in L:
    print variable
```

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: `raw_input("Enter words or numbers...").split()` will split the text in words for you.

Comment: The previous suggestion will split the text into a `list` of words for you.

Comment: ok great. Also, if I want to use phrases like "hello world" and want it to count as one, will this work as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to return a list of the words in the string using the default delimiter of a space character:

```
myList = []

while(True):
    myList = raw_input("Please enter words or numbers: ")
    if(len(myList.split())) <= 5:
        break
    else:
        print("Error: You entered more than 5 arguments, Try again...")

for item in myList.split():
    print(item)
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FF9Y/0)

Answer (score 0):

The working code for what you want is the following:

```
# I separate the input text by the spaces
data = raw_input("Enter something... ").split(" ")

# handle the data
if len(data) > 5:
    print("Only 4 or less arguments allowed!")
else:
    for variable in data:
        print(variable)
```

Now, this doesn't prevent the user from inserting other characters like `!`, `$%"#$`, so to handle that case, you should check for some of the answers in this question: [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Have fun!

Comment: ok great. Also, if I want to use phrases like "hello world" and want it to count as one, will this work as well?

Comment: If you want that behaviour make your user input words separated by commas and use `split(",")`