# Removing all special characters from a string that cannot be used inside the command line (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a tk application in which I have to execute a command line application (MP4Box) from python, using subprocess.check_call(). 
The filename (used in the command)  is retrieved from youtube and hence has all types of special characters. I want to remove all characters that can't be used as filenames in the Operating system also btw (i want the  implementation would work across multiple platforms)

I tried the solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)
. windows seems accept the filename but  but it returns an error with subproces.check_call().
I tried manually removing the special char from filename  and it works good after that. so it isnt a problem with the command.

EDIT:
For eg, i tested for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc) video. The solution in above link won't remove 'ä' and cause a problem in the command line.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. In ordem to allow SO members to better understand your question and to let them help you, it is recommended that you include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VictorDomingos done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the correct answer. Ascii did the trick :)

```
''.join([t for t in <filenmae> if t.isalnum()]).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```