# How to strip random Chars at the end of a String with Regex / Strip() in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, random, strip

What is the preferred way to cut off random characters at the end of a string in Python?

I am trying to simplify a list of URLs to do some analysis and therefore need to cut-off everything that comes after the file extension `.php`

Since the characters that follow after `.php` are different for each URL  using strip() doesn't work. I thought about regex and `substring()`. But what would be the most efficient way to solve this task?

**Example:**

*Let's say I have the following URLs:*

```
example.com/index.php?random_var=random-19wdwka
example.org/index.php?another_var=random-2js9m2msl
```

*And I want the output to be:*

```
example.com/index.php
example.org/index.php
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1276764/1278112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish what you want.

#### If you know how the string ends:

In your example, if You know that the string ends with `.php?` then all you need to do is:

```
my_string.split('?')[0]
```

#### If you don't know how the string ends:

In this case you can use urlparse and take everything but the parameters.

```
from urlparse import urlparse

for url is urls:
    p = urlparse(url)
    print p.scheme + p.netloc + p.path
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer. I know how the string ends, so the first approach works fine, but thanks for the urlparse example!

Answer (score 0):

```
for url in urls:
    result = url.split('?')[0]
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on your separator at most once, and take the first piece:

```
 text="example.com/index.php?random_var=random-19wdwka"
 sep="php"
 rest = text.split(sep)[0]+".php"
 print rest
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want are to strip away the parameters of the URL, you can also use

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

urlunparse(urlparse(url)[:3] + ('', '', ''))
```

to replace the params, query and fragment parts of the URL with empty strings and generate a new one.