# Regex to remove all non-alphabet / non-digit characters [Python]?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

`d = {'<word>':1,'-word':12, 'word':1, '$(*#%&^#&@#':2, '!@**$12word*&':4, '::':10, '1230324':1, '+635':5}`

I want to remove only the entries which are all non-alphabet/non-digit characters, i.e. `,` `.` `?` `!` `:` `;` and so on.

I've tried the following

```
regex = re.compile('[\!\?\.\,\:\;\*\(\)\-\+\<\>]')
regex = re.compile('a-zA-Z0-9_')
regex = re.compile('\\W')
regex = re.compile('[\W_]+') // from [1]
```

but they won't return my desired result, which is:

```
new_dict = {'<word>':1,'-word':12, 'word':1, '!@**$word*&':4, '1230324':1, '+635':5}
```

in which entries `'$(*#%&^#&@#'` and `::` are removed.

Also, I use this code to remove the entries, in case it helps:

```
new_dict = {k:dictionary[k] for k in dictionary if re.match(regex, k)}
```

[1] [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match the whole string for \W with `^\W+$`.

Something like this will do:

```
$ cat test.py
import re

pattern = r"^\W+$"

d = {'<word>':1,'-word':12, 'word':1, '$(*#%&^#&@#':2, '!@**$12word*&':4, '::':10, '1230324':1, '+635':5}

for k in d.keys():
    matches = re.search(pattern, k)
    if (matches):
        print 'to remove: ' + k
        del d[k]

for k in d.keys():
    print k
```

**EDIT**: question changed: OP wants to create dict in one go. Can be done like this:

```
new_dict = {k:d[k] for k in d.keys() if not(re.search(pattern,k))}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I just needed to make a copy of the dictionary first and use that for the loop because this code alone produces an error, saying that 'dictionary changed size during iteration'.