# Python - Remove non alphanumeric characters but keep spaces and Spanish/Portuguese characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Say I have

```
text = "El próximo AÑO, vamos a salir a Curaçao... :@ :) será el día #MIÉRCOLES 30!!!!"
```

How can I turn it into

```
text2 = "El próximo AÑO vamos a salir a Curaçao será el día MIÉRCOLES 30"
```

Using regex?

Comment: May be this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need compatibility with Python 2.7 you can use the `str.isalpha()` method:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
text = u"El próximo AÑO, vamos a salir a Curaçao... :@ :) será el día #MIÉRCOLES 30!!!!"
print(re.sub(' +', ' ', ''.join(c for c in text if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c.isspace())))
```

This outputs:

```
El próximo AÑO vamos a salir a Curaçao será el día MIÉRCOLES 30
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: One last question... What if I wanted "Vamos en la ruta Bogotá-Medellín" to become "Vamos en la ruta Bogotá Medellín"?

Comment: In that case `print(re.sub(' +', ' ', ''.join(c if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c.isspace() else ' ' for c in text)).strip())` will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `\W` character class:

```
re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text)
```

Comment: Note that this will not remove underscores.

Comment: Returns 'El pr ximo A O vamos a salir a Cura ao ser el d a MI RCOLES 30 '

Comment: @NicolasVega What version of Python are you using? And on what platform?

Comment: Python 2.7 on Pycharm.

Comment: Good point @blhsing. I'm sorry it didn't work for you, Nicolas... It worked for me on Python 3 but it does not work on Python 2.7. We'll have to handle Unicode.

Comment: For python2.7 you can modify it to: `re.sub(re.compile(r'\W+',re.UNICODE), ' ', text)`