# Error while removing punctuations and numbers from text file

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to clean up a text file by removing punctuations, numbers and 
 etc.

I wrote this code to try removing punctuations initially :

```
import string
with open("uniquewords_list.txt") as f:

         L = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f for word in line.split())
         
         out = L.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)

         with open('testing.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
              for listitem in out:
                  filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

However I am getting an error :

```
out = L.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

I looked up the error description but still not able to fix it. Suggestions ?

**Also, to delete numbers and characters like 
 what is an efficient way to do ?**

Comment: It's clear on the error. I think this line of code you have here `L = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f for word in line.split())` returns a list type and you are trying to use a `translate` attribute as what it says and it does not have that. I think you just need to check what output type you really want on this `L = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f for word in line.split())` code. What output or output type are you really expecting for it to use a `.translate`?

Comment: What do you want to leave? Just alphabets and whitespaces?

Comment: Yes, just the words i.e. alphabets

Comment: `string.maketrans()` apperars to be a Python 2 feature, are you really using Python 2? Modern projects should usually target the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: no i am using python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
with open("uniquewords_list.txt") as f:

     contents = f.read()
     remove_pool = string.punctuation + '0123456789'  # + etc
     contents = ''.join(ch for ch in contents if ch not in remove_pool)

     with open('testing.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
          filehandle.write(contents + '\n')
```

Comment: Might also want to check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python). Mine's just a simple solution, not the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you can't call `translate` method on an object which is a `list`.  The `str` objects which are the members of the list have this method, though.

Here is a simple idiomatic list comprehension which iterates over each member of the list and calls its `translate` method individually:

```py
out = [x.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation) for x in L]
```

If you are a beginner, perhaps this equivalent longhand code will be more readable:

```py
out = []
for x in L:
    out.append(x.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation))
```

Of course, only calling `maketrans` once would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am a beginner and its exciting to look at the different ways things can be done.