# How to find unknown character from a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

How would I delete an unknown character from a list of strings?
For example my list is `['hi', 'h@w', 'are!', 'you;', '25']` and I want to delete all the characters that are not words or numbers?

How would I do this?

Comment: I think the word character could mean several different things.  You may want to be more specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Probably the cleanest way would be to use a `regex` to parse the string. You could also make an array of invalid characters and `replace` any in the string with an empty string

Answer (score 2):

[Regex:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
s = ['hi', 'h@w', 'are!', 'you;', '25']
[re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', x) for x in s]
```

```
['hi', 'hw', 'are', 'you', '25']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub`:

```
from re import sub
lst = ['hi', 'h@w', 'are!', 'you;', '25']
lst = [sub('[^\w]', '', i) for i in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['hi', 'hw', 'are', 'you', '25']
```

Explanation:

This line: `sub('[^\w]', '', i)` tells python to replace all the substrings of pattern `"[^\w]"` with an empty string, `""` inside the `i` string, and return the result.

The pattern `[^\w]` finds all the characters in a string that are not letters or numbers.