# How to remove non-alphanumeric characters from keys and values in a dictionary and then write it to a text file?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, text-files

Currently I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Coronavirus&action=edit': {'e'}, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=COVID-19_pandemic&action=edit': {'[update]'}, 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/conditionsanddiseases/datasets/coronaviruscovid19infectionsurveydata': {'ONS'}
```

I want to remove the non alphanumeric characters at the beginning and end of each key and value so it looks like this:

{http://google.com: [Google, That one search engine], http://purdue.edu: [Purdue University]}

Also one more question. How would I write my cleaned dictionary to a txt file with the values of the dictionary indented below the key?  I know this is a lot but I need help please. Thanks

Comment: But why your dictionaries have sets in them for no apparent reason ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python
I'm not sure if you want to deserialize the string to a native python objects first... because in that case, some of the non alphanumeric characters - like @Tanishq Banyal metioned - are sets

Comment: This question is indecipherable. I vote to close it. Edit the question to include data that clearly shows how input and output are related. Also post the code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to remove alphanumeric characters or remove payloads from url.

**But For Writing to text file you can first make a string out of dictionary and then replace `,` with `,\n`. And then write it to file.**