# I need to format text from Selenium, cleaning all special characters

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, text

I want to remove all special characters in `name`, but i did a dirty code. Someone know a better way for help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set driver and time for wait in chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
wait: WebDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Open music link
driver.get('https://youtu.be/IJvV7qy0xQM')

# Set xpath of music name
Name_Music_xpath = '//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string'

# Waits until name appears
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Name_Music_xpath)))

# Save name
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Name_Music_xpath)

Original_name = name.text
Formatted_name = name.text

# I want to format music name but, i just know this way to make it
# I need to clear, removing everything that is not letter like ()  &  .  -
Formatted_name = Formatted_name.replace(')', '')
Formatted_name = Formatted_name.replace('(', '')
Formatted_name = Formatted_name.replace('&', '')
Formatted_name = Formatted_name.replace('.', '')
Formatted_name = Formatted_name.replace('-', '')

# Print the original name, and the format that i need
print(Original_name)
print(Formatted_name)
```

**SOLVED CODE:**

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Function to remove special characters
def remove_chars(input: str):
    cleaned_input = re.sub(r'[()&.-]', '', input)
    return " ".join(cleaned_input.split())


# Set driver and time for wait in chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
wait: WebDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Open music link
driver.get('https://youtu.be/IJvV7qy0xQM')

# Set xpath of music name
Name_Music_xpath = '//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string'

# Waits until name appears
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Name_Music_xpath)))

# Save name
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Name_Music_xpath)

Original_name = name.text
Formatted_name = remove_chars(name.text)

print(Original_name)
print(Formatted_name)
```

Comment: If you can extract your `name`, make it more specific; that is, shows us what's this variable, and what the output should look like

Comment: @crissal I just want the output is the same name of music but without special characters, this music for example, in name have **() . & -** and i want remove this

Comment: can digits stay?

Comment: Yes, but if no possible is ok

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will remove the characters you used in your code:

```py
import re

def remove_chars(input: str):
    return re.sub(r'[()&.-]', '', input)
```

This function uses the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module in Python, used for assisting with regular expressions. It returns the input string devoid of the `(`, `)`, `&`, `.`, and `-` characters.

You can use this function in your code like so:

```py
Original_name = name.text
Formatted_name = remove_chars(name.text)
```

Comment: `def` instead of `function`

Comment: @crissal Sure hahaha

Comment: That is exactly i needed, a clean way to solve this, thanks bro <333