# Strip non Alphanumeric chars from filename - php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am working on a rename function to get rid of non alphanumeric chars in a file name.

After some searching in the forums I found a good solution to get rid of those chars but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
echo $filename."\n";
$newfilenamecorrect=preg_replace("/^[a-z0-9A-Z.-_]+$/", '',$filename);
$newfilenamecorrect=dirname($path). '/' . $newfilenamecorrect;
echo $newfilenamecorrect."\n";
```

Where `$filename` is the filename itself (example Picture.jpg),
`$path` - is the original path + filename (example ./galleries/Picture.jpg)
`$newfilenamecorrect` Should be the new filename including path and filename.

No idea why but when I run that I get echoes like:

```
000���5.jpg ./galleries/iPhone/000���5.jpg
2D-Art-Iataândesson-Cruz-Gnomon.jpg ./galleries/iPhone/2D-Art-Iataândesson-Cruz-Gnomon.jpg
```

I'm kinda new to php, so sorry for any stupid mistakes I've made :)

Comment: Try `"/[^\w.-]+/u"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840948/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: not sure, once you use the u modifier, you extend the `\w` character class to unicode, and I think that Shachar Adar looks for only ascii alnum. I suggest: `/[^0-9a-z_.-]/iu` or `/(*UTF8)[^\w.-]/`

Comment: remove the start ^ and end $ chars => /[a-z0-9A-Z.-_]+/

Comment: @nogad thanks that actually solved my problem! I used `$newfilenamecorrect=preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9._-]+/i", '',$filename);` instead of `$newfilenamecorrect=preg_replace("/^[a-z0-9A-Z.-_]+$/", '',$filename);`  I have no idea why the original didn't work.